# What is a passthrough mode in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I recently came across something called the *passthrough* mode in selenium changelog. I quite did not understand its use. can somebody explain about it.

Comment: Where you read that terms

Comment: Will be easier to explain if you are comfortable with Grid Configuration

Comment: Its in this link - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG and yes I am comfortable with selenium grid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `enablepassThrough` mode was added to support the new w3c standard

**Words from Simon Stewart:**

> I've added a "-enablePassThrough" flag to the standalone server. With this in place, and a few tweaks to Grid, it's possible to use a w3c remote end (eg. geckodriver) with a w3c speaking local end (eg. a recent 3.x release of selenium) It'll be in 3.5
>
> Notably, this means that you'll need to start the nodes with "-enablePassThrough".

Please the below issue

[Grid does not handle w3c capabilities correctly #3808](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3808)

Comment: May be a little dumb question but does this mean its not required to have a driver executable in the remote machine ?

Comment: It will be needed still, this flag is just to make it compatible with the latest w3c standard driver

Comment: @KeerthiS, if it does solve your question, don't forget to accept it as an answer